# Rails 4 has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

I'm pretty new to Rails. I did the following migration:

```
def change
  add_reference   :orders, :table, index: true
  add_foreign_key :orders, :tables
end
```

And I have following models:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

has_one :table
end
```

In console I have:

```
 o = Order.new
 o.name = "pippo"
 o.user_id = 4
 o.table_id=Table.first.id
 o.save
 o.table
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column tables.order_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "tables".* FROM "tables" WHERE "tables"."order_id" =...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Order has one table then table needs the order's foreign key. So you actually run the opposite migrations. Table should have order_id foreign key.

```
 def change
  add_reference   :tables, :order, index: true
  add_foreign_key :tables, :orders
 end
```

Then create a table record with order_id and call Order#table.

Comment: I'm just about to write this :)

Comment: If this answer is the right answer you can accept this as right answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rubyrider, I'm going to accept your answer in five minutes

Comment: If you are using MySQL InnoDB, you don't need the index, foreign key automatically does that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: this is not the question here, nor the issue.